# Delete certain rows in a group of rows in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have this dataset

```
Id Name Price sales Profit Month Category Mode Supplier
1    A     2     0      0     1        X    K     John
1    A     2     0      0     2        X    K     John
1    A     2     5      8     3        X    K     John
1    A     2     5      8     4        X    L      Sam
2    B     2     3      4     1        X    L      Sam
2    B     2     0      0     2        X    L      Sam
2    B     2     0      0     3        X    M     John
2    B     2     0      0     4        X    L     John
3    C     2     0      0     1        X    K     John
3    C     2     8     10     2        Y    M     John
3    C     2     8     10     3        Y    K     John
3    C     2     0      0     4        Y    K     John
5    E     2     0      0     1        Y    M      Sam
5    E     2     5      5     2        Y    L      Sam
5    E     2     5      9     3        Y    M      Sam
5    E     2     0      0     4        Z    M     Kyle
5    E     2     5      8     5        Z    L     Kyle
5    E     2     5      8     6        Z    M     Kyle
```

I want to delete rows with zeroes for `Sales` and `Profit` column by `Id` group
So for a certain `Id` if two or more consecutive rows have zero values for `sales` and `profit` those rows will get delete. So this dataset will become like this.

```
Id Name Price sales Profit Month Category Mode Supplier
1    A     2     5      8     3        X    K     John
1    A     2     5      8     4        X    L      Sam
2    B     2     3      4     1        X    L      Sam
3    C     2     0      0     1        X    K     John
3    C     2     8     10     2        Y    M     John
3    C     2     8     10     3        Y    K     John
3    C     2     0      0     4        Y    K     John
5    E     2     0      0     1        Y    M      Sam
5    E     2     5      5     2        Y    L      Sam
5    E     2     5      9     3        Y    M      Sam
5    E     2     0      0     4        Z    M     Kyle
5    E     2     5      8     5        Z    L     Kyle
5    E     2     5      8     6        Z    M     Kyle
```

I can remove all rows if they have zero values for `Sales` and `Profit` with

```
df1 = df[!(df$sales==0 & test$Profit==0),]
```

But how to delete rows only in certain group in this case by Id

P.S The idea is to delete entries for those products if they started selling after few months or got abandoned after few months in a year cycle.

Comment: Write a simple function that does the deletion and includes/excludes the groups you want. Then use any of `lapply` a `for` loop, `data.table`, or `(d)plyr` to split-apply-combine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach using `rleid` from "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydf)[, N := .N, by = .(Id, rleid(sales == 0 & Profit == 0))][
    !(sales == 0 & Profit == 0 & N >= 2)]
##     Id Name Price sales Profit Month Category Mode Supplier N
##  1:  1    A     2     5      8     3        X    K     John 2
##  2:  1    A     2     5      8     4        X    L      Sam 2
##  3:  2    B     2     3      4     1        X    L      Sam 1
##  4:  3    C     2     0      0     1        X    K     John 1
##  5:  3    C     2     8     10     2        Y    M     John 2
##  6:  3    C     2     8     10     3        Y    K     John 2
##  7:  3    C     2     0      0     4        Y    K     John 1
##  8:  5    E     2     0      0     1        Y    M      Sam 1
##  9:  5    E     2     5      5     2        Y    L      Sam 2
## 10:  5    E     2     5      9     3        Y    M      Sam 2
## 11:  5    E     2     0      0     4        Z    M     Kyle 1
## 12:  5    E     2     5      8     5        Z    L     Kyle 2
## 13:  5    E     2     5      8     6        Z    M     Kyle 2
```

Comment: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "rleid"
got this error, i have installed and loaded data.table package.

Comment: @Jaykhan, what version of "data.table" are you using? What OS are you on?

Comment: data table of 1.9.6 and using OSX El Captain

Comment: @Jaykhan, I really don't know why the function wouldn't be there.... Restart your session and verify that you've got 1.9.6 loaded?

Comment: Uninstall the package and reinstall again. This kind of issues are usually fixed by just removing and reinstalling.

Comment: @Jaykhan, See Arun's comment above. Try that and let us know if you're still having problems....

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it with `dplyr`. Basically, I'm only keeping lines that are not zero OR that the previous/following lines is not zero.

```
table1 %>%
group_by(Id) %>%
mutate(Lag=lag(sales),Lead=lead(sales)) %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(Min=min(Lag,Lead,na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
filter(sales>0|Min>0)  %>%
select(-Lead,-Lag,-Min)

      Id  Name Price sales Profit Month Category  Mode Supplier
   (int) (chr) (int) (int)  (int) (int)    (chr) (chr)    (chr)
1      1     A     2     5      8     3        X     K     John
2      1     A     2     5      8     4        X     L      Sam
3      2     B     2     3      4     1        X     L      Sam
4      3     C     2     0      0     1        X     K     John
5      3     C     2     8     10     2        Y     M     John
6      3     C     2     8     10     3        Y     K     John
7      3     C     2     0      0     4        Y     K     John
8      5     E     2     0      0     1        Y     M      Sam
9      5     E     2     5      5     2        Y     L      Sam
10     5     E     2     5      9     3        Y     M      Sam
11     5     E     2     0      0     4        Z     M     Kyle
12     5     E     2     5      8     5        Z     L     Kyle
13     5     E     2     5      8     6        Z     M     Kyle
```

**Data**

```
table1 <-read.table(text="
Id,Name,Price,sales,Profit,Month,Category,Mode,Supplier
1,A,2,0,0,1,X,K,John
1,A,2,0,0,2,X,K,John
1,A,2,5,8,3,X,K,John
1,A,2,5,8,4,X,L,Sam
2,B,2,3,4,1,X,L,Sam
2,B,2,0,0,2,X,L,Sam
2,B,2,0,0,3,X,M,John
2,B,2,0,0,4,X,L,John
3,C,2,0,0,1,X,K,John
3,C,2,8,10,2,Y,M,John
3,C,2,8,10,3,Y,K,John
3,C,2,0,0,4,Y,K,John
5,E,2,0,0,1,Y,M,Sam
5,E,2,5,5,2,Y,L,Sam
5,E,2,5,9,3,Y,M,Sam
5,E,2,0,0,4,Z,M,Kyle
5,E,2,5,8,5,Z,L,Kyle
5,E,2,5,8,6,Z,M,Kyle
",sep=",",stringsAsFactors =FALSE, header=TRUE)
```

**UPDATE**
To filter on more than one column with these criteria, here's how to do it. In the present case, the result is the same because when sales are 0, profits are also 0.

```
library(dplyr)
table1 %>%
group_by(Id) %>%
mutate(LagS=lag(sales),LeadS=lead(sales),LagP=lag(Profit),LeadP=lead(Profit)) %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(MinS=min(LagS,LeadS,na.rm=TRUE),MinP=min(LagP,LeadP,na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
filter(sales>0|MinS>0|Profit>0|MinP>0)  %>%         # "|" means OR
select(-LeadS,-LagS,-MinS,-LeadP,-LagP,-MinP)
```

Comment: By the way, this is not quite what the OP wants. Look at 8. line of the desired result.

Comment: @PLapointe its deleting based on one variable Sales, right? I want to delete rows with zero based on 2 or more variables value. How to do that?

Comment: I updated my code for criteria on more than one column but the result is the same for your specific example because when sales are 0, profits are also 0.

Answer (score 1):

I can't do it in one line, but here it is in three:

```
x <- df$sales==0 & df$Profit==0
y <- cumsum(c(1,head(x,-1)!=tail(x,-1)))
df[ave(x,df$Id,y,FUN=sum)<2,]

#    Id Name Price sales Profit Month Category Mode Supplier
# 3   1    A     2     5      8     3        X    K     John
# 4   1    A     2     5      8     4        X    L      Sam
# 5   2    B     2     3      4     1        X    L      Sam
# 9   3    C     2     0      0     1        X    K     John
# 10  3    C     2     8     10     2        Y    M     John
# 11  3    C     2     8     10     3        Y    K     John
# 12  3    C     2     0      0     4        Y    K     John
# 13  5    E     2     0      0     1        Y    M      Sam
# 14  5    E     2     5      5     2        Y    L      Sam
# 15  5    E     2     5      9     3        Y    M      Sam
# 16  5    E     2     0      0     4        Z    M     Kyle
# 17  5    E     2     5      8     5        Z    L     Kyle
# 18  5    E     2     5      8     6        Z    M     Kyle
```

This works by first identifying all rows where `sales` and `Profit` are both 0 (`x`).  The variable `y` groups consecutive `TRUE` and `FALSE` values. The `ave()` function splits the first input variable (`x`) according to the subsequent input variables (`df$Id` and `y`) then applies the function within groups.  Since the function is `sum()`, it will add up all the `TRUE` values in `x`, then it returns a vector of the same length as `x`, so we just need to keep all the rows where the result is less than 2.

Comment: When i tried to apply the code on original data of more than 500,000 rows, it breaks down with error that long vectors not supported yet:

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution:

```
aux <- lapply(tapply(df$sales + df$Profit, df$Id, rle), function(x) 
       with(x, cbind(rep(values, lengths), rep(lengths, lengths))))

df[!(do.call(rbind, aux)[,1]==0 & do.call(rbind, aux)[,2] >= 2),]

   Id Name Price sales Profit Month Category Mode Supplier
3   1    A     2     5      8     3        X    K     John
4   1    A     2     5      8     4        X    L      Sam
5   2    B     2     3      4     1        X    L      Sam
9   3    C     2     0      0     1        X    K     John
10  3    C     2     8     10     2        Y    M     John
11  3    C     2     8     10     3        Y    K     John
12  3    C     2     0      0     4        Y    K     John
13  5    E     2     0      0     1        Y    M      Sam
14  5    E     2     5      5     2        Y    L      Sam
15  5    E     2     5      9     3        Y    M      Sam
16  5    E     2     0      0     4        Z    M     Kyle
17  5    E     2     5      8     5        Z    L     Kyle
18  5    E     2     5      8     6        Z    M     Kyle
```

Comment: When i tried to apply the code on original data of more than 500,000 rows, it breaks down with error that long vectors not supported yet: