# Delete consecutive rows in a group of rows for large datasets in R

Tags: r

I have a little bit complicated problem to solve.

Suppose I have this dataset

```
Id Name Price sales Profit Month Category Mode Supplier
1    A     0     0      0     1        X    K     John
1    A     0     0      0     2        X    K     John
1    A     0     0      0     3        X    K     John
1    A     2     5      0     4        X    L      Sam
1    A     2     3      4     5        X    L      Sam
1    A     0     0      0     6        X    L      Sam
2    C     2     4      9     1        X    M     John
2    C     0     0      0     2        X    L     John
2    C     0     0      0     3        X    K     John
2    C     2     8      0     4        Y    M     John
2    C     2     8     10     5        Y    K     John
2    C     0     0      0     6        Y    K     John
3    E     0     0      0     1        Y    M      Sam
3    E     0     0      0     2        Y    L      Sam
3    E     2     5      9     3        Y    M      Sam
3    E     0     0      0     4        Z    M     Kyle
3    E     0     0      0     5        Z    L     Kyle
3    E     0     0      0     6        Z    M     Kyle
```

Now I want to delete those rows from the data frame, for those products `Id` which have zero value for `Price, sales`and`profit` for three consecutive months. How to delete rows only in certain group in this case by Id

Expected output

```
Id Name Price sales Profit Month Category Mode Supplier
1    A     2     5      0     4        X    L      Sam
1    A     2     3      4     5        X    L      Sam
1    A     0     0      0     6        X    L      Sam
2    C     2     4      9     1        X    M     John
2    C     0     0      0     2        X    L     John
2    C     0     0      0     3        X    K     John
2    C     2     8      0     4        Y    M     John
2    C     2     8     10     5        Y    K     John
2    C     0     0      0     6        Y    K     John
3    E     0     0      0     1        Y    M      Sam
3    E     0     0      0     2        Y    L      Sam
3    E     2     5      9     3        Y    M      Sam
```

This is just a reproducible sample, my original data has more than 800k rows. So I am looking for some function which can achieve this on large data set too.

I have tried using approaches mentioned to me before like

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydf)[, N := .N, by = .(Id, rleid(Price == 0 & sales == 0 & Profit == 0))][
    !(Price==0 & sales == 0 & Profit == 0 & N >= 2)]
```

This one when I tried received error that `'could not find rleid function'` and i had the `data.table` package install and loaded

P.S I have asked this question before and couple of solutions in other post only worked on small data and didn't receive answer which can solve this kind of problem on large data set so that's why I am asking again.

Comment: In order to delete the rows of a product id that has zeros three consecutive months do the rows need to have only the id identical or also other columns like category, mode or supplier?

Comment: Maybe you need to update the `data.table` package you installed.

Comment: Do you have `packageVersion("data.table") >= "1.9.6"`? Look at the [version history](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table).

Comment: @VenYao I installed fresh copy of data.table twice from different servers. still same issue.

Comment: You know that asking the [same question twice in the same day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294171/delete-certain-rows-in-a-group-of-rows-in-r) doesn't increase your odds to get an answer?

Comment: @iled different time zones, maybe last night some people were sleeping who are awake now. :)

Comment: @iled technically its a new question, last question got some answers which work well on small data set. but i want solution for large data set and those techniques doesnt work on that. So if i edit my last post, it will undermine the answers which worked well on small data set.

Comment: Could you give us the code to reproduce that data please?

Answer (score 0):

It's rather "home-made" but maybe will help (my example is a little bit simpler, but idea is the same):

```
library("dplyr")

# just an example:

month <- rep(1:7, 3)
id <- rep(c("A", "C", "E"), each=7)
price <- c(0,0,0,2,2,0,2,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0, 1, 1, 1)
sales <- c(0,0,0,4,3,0,2,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,3,0,0,0, 1, 1, 1)
supplier <- rep(c("john", "anna", "ben"), 7)

data.frame(id, price, sales, month, supplier) -> dane

# lag from a vector shows everything but first element and first element become NA:

lag1_sales <- lag(dane$sales)
lag2_sales <- lag(dane$sales, 2) # the same, but without two first elements

lag1_price <- lag(dane$price)
lag2_price <- lag(dane$price, 2)

# I add it to data_frame as columns:

dane <- cbind(dane, lag1_sales, lag2_sales, lag1_price, lag2_price)

# mutate creates new column with 1 if sales and price and it's two lags are equal 1, so that I have a marker when was three zeros:

dane %>% 
    mutate(marker=ifelse(sales==0 & price==0 & 
                             lag1_sales==0 & lag2_sales==0 &
                             lag1_price==0 & lag2_price==0, 1, 0)) -> dane

# marker2 and marker3 are made to marker two rows above this triple markered above:

marker2 <- c(dane$marker[-1], NA)
marker3 <- c(dane$marker[-c(1, 2)], NA, NA)

dane <- cbind(dane, marker2, marker3)

# I take only rows, which are marked:

dane %>% 
    filter(!(marker==1 | marker2==1 | marker3==1)) -> new_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer. This code deletes the rows even if there are three consecutive months like this for example `months: 2,5,6`

```
#Generate data
month <- rep(1:7, 3)
id <- rep(c("1", "2", "3"), each=7)
price <- c(0,0,0,2,2,0,2,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0, 1, 1, 1)
sales <- c(0,0,0,4,3,0,2,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,3,0,0,0, 1, 1, 1)
test <- data.frame(id, price, sales, month)

#Calculate how many consecutive times a combination of id, 
#price & sales is encountered
sequence <- rle(paste(test$id,test$price,test$sales,sep=""))

#calculate the row indexes to keep
index <- with(sequence, lengths != 3 )
index2 <- unlist(sapply(c(1:length(index)),FUN=function(x){
  seq(from=index[x],to=index[x],length.out=sequence$lengths[x])
}))

#store results:
test2 <- test[index2,]
```